# iphone se 2020 32Gb or 64Gb for $20?

Tags: iphone

I'm looking at used phones.

Hi I'm looking at used iphones, is it worth getting the 64Gb?
I feel I could get away with the 32Gb + Sd card, light use just browsing video + web mostly maybe a game thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot tell you what is or isn't worth it. You have to decide that for yourself - but note that the USB card reader would be another $£€35.

Answer (score 1):

Only you can answer how much data you think you are going to put on the phone.

You can of course use iCloud to hold most of your photos, files, music, etc; and only download a fraction to your phone as you need it: but that will involve more data usage and iCloud storage subscriptions.